# How to prepare this function for integration

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I want to prepare $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$ for integration, how do i get the $1+x^2$ to the top?

Is $$\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$ the same as $\frac x1 + \frac{x}{x^2}$? If not please explain how I prepare the following function for integration.

Comment: Just substitute: $u=1+x^2$.

Comment: Do you want to integrate $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: It is surprising that the second question (whether $\frac{1}{2} = 2$) comes up a lot in the context of integration although most people know that it's wrong when they're not talking about integration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b+c} \neq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{c}$.

So you can't simply split up the integrand as you did.

However, it is true that $\displaystyle \frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c}$, so you might be confusing this with that.

To evaluate your integral, simply make the substitution $\displaystyle u = 1 + x^2$. Remember that $du = 2xdx$, so $\displaystyle dx = \frac{1}{2x}du$, which will allow you to greatly simplify the integral.

Comment: I feel uneasy whenever I see things like $$ \text{d}u = 2x \text{ d}x \implies \text{d}x = \dfrac{\text{d}u}{2x} $$ It'd be much easier to simply manipulate the numerator instead $$ \int \dfrac{x}{1+x^2} \text{ d}x = \dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2} \text{ d}x $$

Comment: @Shisui It is acceptable (Leibniz) notation for separation of variables. It can be seen in many sources. It's often much easier for beginners to understand what's going on with this notation than to eschew it and try to get them to see integrands of the form $\displaystyle \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ immediately.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

You do not need to have $1+x^2$ in the top. Just notice that the derivative of the denominator is $2x$ that is to say very similar to the numerator. So, try to put it into something looking as $\frac {u'(x)}{u(x)}$

Comment: the answer would be (1/2)log(1+x^2). yes

Comment: Recognising the form is better practice than substitution, in this case. When the asker is faced with integrating $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ later, substitution isn't going to help. But when the asker is faced with integrating $x\cos(1+x^2)$, this answer is going to help.

Comment: You are perfectly right, indeed. I was just answering OP' specific casz. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is $$\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$ the same as $\frac x1 + \frac{x}{x^2}$?

I'm sorry to say this, but if you do not know that this is absolutely not true, then you must learn **A LOT** more before you can start learning integration.

Comment: This should be a comment ;-)

Comment: @ringo The way quoting works (or rather, doesn't work) in comments, I find it is better to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx^2$$

Comment: That looks extraordinarily unclear. Wouldn't it be better to say this? $$ \int \dfrac{x}{1+x^2} \text{ d}x \ = \dfrac{1}{2} \int \left( \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} x^2 \right) \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} \text{ d}x $$

Comment: I would not call this extraordinary unclear. For $dx^2= 2xdx$. It is merely a hint I gave. I could have given $d(1+x^2)$ in stead of $dx^2$, but then I am giving away more. The OP has to think about it too.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You have the following function

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$ which you want to integrate, so you have

$$\int f(x) \, dx=\frac{x}{1+x^2} \, dx$$

What if you did this: Let $u = 1 + x^2$ and $\frac{1}{2} du = x dx$

Then if you integrate then what will you will get? Try it out.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, I'll edit it accordingly.